# PROC SQL - Case when with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sas

I need to create a dataset (TABLE3) in order to check if some variables from other two tables are equals. If so, the code must return 0, otherwise 1. But, as I'm a new user of SAS and SQL I'm struggling to figure out how to do that.

I'm trying something like that but it's not working.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 AS
SELECT A.*, B.*
CASE WHEN B.VARIABLE1 = A.VARIABLE2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VARIABLE_1_2,
CASE WHEN B.VARIABLE3 = A.VARIABLE4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VARIABLE_3_4
FROM TABLE1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS B;
```

P.S.: Variables 1, 2, 3 and 4 are all character variables.

Comment: You are missing an `on` clause for the join.

Answer (score 0):

For a JOIN condition to work, there must a ON clause

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 AS
SELECT A.*, B.*,
CASE WHEN B.VARIABLE1 = A.VARIABLE2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VARIABLE_1_2,
CASE WHEN B.VARIABLE3 = A.VARIABLE4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VARIABLE_3_4
FROM TABLE1 AS A LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS B
**ON TABLE1.SOME_COLUMN_NAME = TABLE2.SOME_COLUMN_NAME**
;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tables relation you must add after the join, You miss a coma "," just before the first case.